# Cron - gsutil not found

Tags: shell, cron, gsutil

gsutil has been installed here:

```
/usr/local/bin/gsutil
```

My crontab looks like this (i'm logged in as root):

```
 */1  *  *  *  * /home/deploy/cron/job.sh >> /home/deploy/cron/test.log 2>&1
```

job.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="$PATH":/usr/local/bin/gsutil
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%y_%R");
cp /home/deploy/testfile.txt /tmp/testfile_$now.txt;
gsutil cp /home/deploy/testfile.txt gs://testbucket/testfile_$now.txt;

echo "saved file at $now";
```

When I look in my log file I see this:

```
/home/deploy/cron/job.sh: 5: /home/deploy/cron/job.sh: gsutil: not found
saved file at 07_20_15_13:03
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$PATH` does not contain full paths to binaries. It contains paths to the directories that contain the binaries. Either fix the `PATH` assignment or just use the full path to `gsutil` in the call itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Had the same issue, you need to specify the full path when you call `gsutil`.
In your case:

```
/usr/local/bin/gsutil/gsutil cp /home/deploy/testfile.txt gs://testbucket/testfile_$now.txt;
```

Comment: This solution helped me solve this problem, I'd like to add for anyone else that if your path is different for gsutil you can run "which gsutil" to get the correct path, using that path rather than /usr/local/bin/gsutil.

Comment: "whereis  gsutil" will also work

Answer (score 3):

yes, you have use the full path gsutil command to use in crontab

/root/gcloud/gsutil cp ...

Comment: You're right, I am just curious, any idea why this happens?

Also, as pointed out by others, you can use `which gsutil` to find the path.